# Getting ACErrorAccessInfoInvalid on -[FBSession open

Tags: ios, facebook

Calling this:

```
[[self session] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
```

and I'm getting an error:

```
(lldb) po [error userInfo]
(id) $0 = 0x1fde09c0 {
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey" = "Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=8 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 8.)\"";
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason" = "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason";
}
```

I know that "com.apple.accounts error 8" means ACErrorAccessInfoInvalid, but I have no idea how I can fix that, as the code that calls this is buried in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

My default permissions were the problem. Once I removed all the permissions from the creation of the initial FBSession, it worked. HOWEVER I now have to figure out how to ask for those permissions later on.